# Sitecore 9.0 works with solr 7.2.1?

Tags: solr

I have installed `Sitecore 9.1.0 XP` on my system with `Solr 7.2.1`.

I want to install Sitecore 9.0.1 XP also on my system. Should I use `Solr 7.2.1` for this or do I need `Solr 6.6.2`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solr 7.2.1 is not supported by Sitecore 9.0.1 officially.

But does it mean Sitecore 9.0.1 will not work with Solr 7.2.1? No, it doesn't. It means that Sitecore 9.0.1 is not officially tested against that version. And it means that if you will use Solr 7.2.1 with Sitecore 9.0.1 and you experience any issues, Sitecore Support will be allowed to tell you "Sorry, but you're using unsupported version of Solr".

I know about plenty of projects running on **newer Solr versions** than are supported officially and they do work well.

So should you use 7.2.1 for your second project or install 6.6.2? One good answer does not exist.

And here is the compatibilitya fragment of table which is mentioned by @Anton in his answer (table copied from the Sitecore documentation site):

[image]

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to install Solr 6.6.2 on you local system and run it on different port.

Solr 6.6.2 is compatible with Sitecore 9.0.1 XP and it will not break other Sitecore instances on your env.

Answer (score 1):

It is not officially supported. Use [this table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897) to check.

However, if it for you local instance you can use it. For example I have different version of Sitecore, but only 1 version of Solr. But don't do it on servers.