# Does Sitecore 9.X will support solr version 8.X

Tags: solr

Does Sitecore 9.X will support solr version 8.X? 
I have to take some strategic decision on that based on that. So, if any body have insight or tried this then please help me.

Comment: This question is much too broad. All we can do is point you to the SOLR Compatibility Table (https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897) which shows 9.1 is tested/recommended to use Solr 7.2.1.

Comment: Thanks for article link. I already have that. But my question is more towards strategic decision. Because Solr is going to end support for solr 7.x version. That's what i want to know that Is Sitecore 9.2 on wards will support Solr 8.x or not?

Comment: That question can be only answered by Sitecore themselves. You should ask it to your local representative.

Answer (score 0):

I voted to close the question as a duplicate with a similar but not exactly the same question ( [Sitecore 9.0 works with solr 7.2.1?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18918/sitecore-9-0-works-with-solr-7-2-1) ). **But the answer stays the same, just with changes to the versions**:

Solr 8.X is not supported by Sitecore 9.X officially.

But does it mean Sitecore 9.X will not work with Solr 8.X? No, it doesn't. It means that Sitecore 9.1 is not officially tested against that version. And it means that if you will use Solr 8.X with Sitecore 9.X and you experience any issues, Sitecore Support will be allowed to tell you "Sorry, but you're using unsupported version of Solr".

I know about plenty of projects running on newer Solr versions than are supported officially and they do work well.

So should you use 8.X or install 7.2.1? One good answer does not exist.

For the reference: [Solr compatibility table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897)

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Does it means Sitecore 9.x version will work fine with solr 8.x but will not be supported by Sitecore?

Comment: I don't know. I know people who run Sitecore on unsupported Solr versions. They do fine now, but no one knows if there are some edge cases which will not work. And as I mentioned in my comment to your question above, I don't know which Solr versions will be supported by future Sitecore versions.